# Error while pushing code from Visual studio 2015 to VSTS

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, git-push

I have one account in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) on URL: `tempaccount.visualstudio.com`.
I have created repo over there. I opened git on local system and I have cloned repo to local from option over visualstudio.com "clone with VS"
I have 5 basic users in VSTS account. I logged into Visual studio 2015 in my 2 systems - A and B with 2 users from these 5 VSTS users.
Note: these are live IDs.

Then I connect with server which is `tempaccount.visualstudio.com`. Here I can sync (sometimes). Also under both global and repository settings I have kept same users.

Now here is the game: when I pull there seems like smooth way. No error.
But when I push code I get errors like:

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Connection reset by peer).
>
> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (Connection Timed Out).

Where have I done something wrong, can anyone please help to sort this?

Note: I already refer [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385418/tfs-git-repository-fails-to-sync-in-visual-studio-2015) but no use.

Comment: it works good from git bash push operation on same system. I allowed corporate firewall for this URL.

Comment: Are you going through a proxy?

Comment: @MrHinsh I think yes we are using proxy as I need to set Internet option > LAN settings > change proxy > I have entered something/proxy. So it means we are using proxy.

Comment: You can refer to this article to deal with proxy issue: [Proxy Authorization Required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771556.aspx)